# Why am I getting this undefined array key?

Tags: php, html

I'm just trying to loop through the array and echo it 3 times inside the div but here I got confused and why is it throwing me an undefined array key. If I put fixed numeric value inside $arr[i] then its running properly but why isn't it picking up the value of i? What am I missing?
Please help me to solve the problem and Thanks in advance.
Here's the code below.

```
   <?php

      $arr = array("Gallery-1.jpg","Gal-2.jpg","Gal-3.jpg","gal-4.jpg","gal-5.jpg");

      $i = 0;

      for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-programs'>
        <img src='assets/img/portfolio/.$arr[i].' class='img-fluid' alt=''>
        <div class='portfolio-info'>
          <h4>Programs 1</h4>
          <p>Programs</p>
          <a href='assets/img/portfolio/.$arr[i].' data-gallery='portfolioGallery'
            class='portfolio-lightbox preview-link' title='App 1'><i class='bx bx-plus'></i></a>
          
        </div>
      </div>";
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: please change [i]to [$i]

Comment: aaaahh shit!! trying to find for half an hour and I didn't even notice that silly thing.
any way thank you so much...